# Passing multiple arguments in middle of command with xargs

Tags: java, xargs

Is there a way to pass multiple arguments in the middle of a command using xargs?

For example, I have a file `javaoptions.txt` which contains a default set of Java options. I would like to be able to do something like

`xargs -I % java % ClassName < javaoptions.txt`

and have it pass all of the options in to one command. If I try doing this, however, it uses several commands, passing one option in each time.

For what it's worth, I cannot modify the source code that is being executed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to insert the contents of `javaoptions.txt` into your Java command. If so, `xargs` is no help. That's for running the same command on each line of output of another command. All you need here is

```
java $(cat javaoptions.txt) ClassName
```

(... assuming no option contains embedded whitespace or globbing characters etc.)

Personally, however, I would write a function for this that store the options in an array, which would allow me to use options containing whitespace too:

```
runJava(){
   javaOpts=( -Xmx4g -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/foo ) ## random example
   java "${javaOpts[@]}" "$@"  ## run the java command with the options    
}
```

Add that to your `~/.bashrc` (or equivalent for your shell), and you can run:

```
runJava Classname
```

To run

```
java -Xmx4g -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/foo Classname
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
xargs sh -c 'exec java "$@" ClassName' -- < javaoptions.txt
```